# Possible to build an application for linux?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a game which will be based on a (I guess thats the best way for a some sort of pokergame?!) client server architecture.

I am using the Xamarin Plugin for Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin.Forms for my Android client (later I might build a IOS client and a Windows Phone client aswell, thats why I chose Xamarin.Forms).

Since I would like to **not** have a Windows Server, I am about to implement a linux server application, which interacts with my clients.

Now I have two basic questions:

1. Is it possible to build a Linux app with Xamarin's Visual Studio Plugin on Windows? If not, how would you do it?
2. How would you interact with your clients, are there free frameworks, that offer me automated object transportation between client and server? I saw there is a Framework called NetworkComms.NET, but even the non-Commercial version costs real cash.

I'm sorry for this slightly broad/opinion-based question, but I have no idea how to tag or ask this basic questions in a better way.

Comment: Xamarin won't help you, but you don't need any. Just make a console application with .NET and run it on Mono. There are many ways to communicate, but library suggestions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: The standard console application that comes with VS.NET or a specific mono one?

Comment: No need for anything specific, just the regular one. As long as you use what Mono provides (which is most of the .NET) it will run fine.

Comment: Alright, thanks, so I can build my app on my Windows PC and compile it on a Linux Server using mono, right? What about third party libraries like nuget packages? Can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a server application with .NET for Linux you don't need Xamarin. You can use Visual Studio, create a console application and run it with Mono on Linux.

You can use most of what .NET offers, more information on [application portability](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/) on Mono's website.

You can use NuGet packages as long as they are managed code, or there is a Linux native version. Windows native code will not work directly on Linux. Some native libraries, like SQLite, are available with Mono and will work without issues.

You can build the application with Visual Studio and then deploy the binaries on Linux when needed, or you can compile the whole thing with Mono. The latter might show the hidden errors if you use some parts of .NET that Mono doesn't provide, but in regular development those won't come up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) What you're suggesting is to compile the assemblies not with VS but with MonoDevelop for example? It will take the code and compile it using the mono Framework while VS takes the standard .NET Framework right?

Comment: @Jannik I'd suggest at least testing the compilation with Mono to see if it finds any issues. But you can also develop entirely with MonoDevelop if you want, then you'll be using the things Mono allows all the time.

Comment: The reason why I am asking that much is because I had problems yesterday with the IPAddress class. Xamarin.Forms didnt support it, because it internally uses win-specific things like socketing. Since Xamarin uses mono, my mono console app will not know IPAddress aswell right?

Comment: @Jannik Mono does have [IPAddress](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/IPAddress.cs) implemented and it is shown in [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.IPAddress/) also, don't know why it wouldn't be usable with Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Well, maybe I was wrong and I was missing some references, I will verify it again when I'm home